# How do I override the setter method of a property in C#?

Tags: c#, get, properties, overriding, set

I have a class with a subclass. The superclass has a `Position` property. The subclass must perform an additional operation when the `Position` property is changed, so I am attempting to override the setter method and call the superclass' setter.

I think I've got the superclass setter calling part down, but I can't figure out how the overriding syntax works here.

Here is my best attempt:
[image: code]

The getter is there just for proof of concept -- suppose I wanted to override that too?

The getter and setter give me errors of this form:

> cannot override inherited member 'superClassName.Position.[gs]et' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override

Here's a screencap of the errors too for good measure:
[image: errors]

I also tried using the override keyword in front of the `set`. Removing the superfluous getter has no effect.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Also note that you are overriding the getter, if the purpose of the code was to use the base class Position and call SnapBodyToPos() when a value is set, you also have to change the "get" to "return base.Position" instead of "return pos"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The override is fine. However, as the error message states, you need to mark the property in the base class as virtual to be able to override it:

```
public virtual Vector2 Position
```

Unlike Java, class members are not virtual by default in C#. If you can't change the base class, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, that's what got me. I'm making C# but thinking Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Your `Position` property isn't virtual in the base class, so you can't override it. If you make it virtual, you should be able to override it.

It gets a bit messy overriding one bit without the other - it's not the kind of thing I do very often, so I'd have to play around with it to make sure of what's going on, but the *first* thing to do would be to change the base class property...

This is also exactly what the compiler message is telling you:

> cannot override inherited member 'superClassName.Position.[gs]et' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override

It's telling you something about the base class property - so that's what you need to change in order to override it. Compiler messages are there to help - pay close attention to them!

Answer (score 6):

in your base class: add keyword `virtual`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is pointed out to you in the error message :)

You cannot override members that aren't virtual (or abstract) in the first place.

Your superclass needs to have `virtual` in the property definition:

```
public virtual Vector2 Position { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override members not marked as `virtual` or `abstract`

Mark your `Vector2` property in a super class as `virtual`.

```
public virtual Vector2 Position
```